# Serialize structure

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I have basically no knowledge of data management in this language. I'm using the [dynaTrees](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynaTree/index.html) package to do some machine learning and I'd like to export the model to a file for further use.

The model is obtained by calling the `dynaTrees` function:

```
model <- dynaTrees(
    as.matrix(training.data[,-1]),
    as.matrix(training.data[, 1]),
    R=10
)
```

I then want to export this `model` object so it can be loaded in another script later on. I tried the simple:

```
write(model, file="model.dat")
```

but that doesn't work (type list not supported).

Is there a generic way (or a dedicated package) in R to export complex data structure to file?

Comment: you can use `save(model, file = "model.Rda")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `saveRDS` (see `? saveRDS` for details). Example:

```
saveRDS(model, file = "model.Rds")
```

This saves a single R object to file so that you can restore it later (using `readRDS`). `save` is an alternative that is designed for saving multiple R objects (or an entire workspace), which can be accessed later using `load`.

Your intuition was to use the `write` function, which is actually a rarely used tool for writing a matrix to a text representation. Here's an example:

```
write(as.matrix(warpbreaks[1:3,]), file = stdout())
# 26
# 30
# 54
# A
# A
# A
# L
# L
# L
```